# HTML / JAVASCRIPT with no database like MySQL

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help. I need to write a program in **HTML/JAVASCRIPT** without using  any database such as MySQL, etc. I hope you can help me. For example,

```
Pedro = North
Juan = North
Ana = South
Marie = South
```

My problem is ..
 If in `textbox1` I write `Pedro` and `textbox2` I write `Juan` then `textbox3` should display the word `TRUE` because they're **both North**(`textbox3` should display `TRUE` if both values are the same, `and` if the `textbox1` is `Pedro` and `textbox2` is `Marie` `then` `textbox3` display `FALSE` because they are `not` the same category.

Comment: How could you possibly achieve this without comparing it to some database of predetermined names/gender relationships. What if someone was to input Jackie?

Comment: You're just asking us to write you the code that compare 2 values and display `TRUE` if they match. How the girl/boy part got anything to do with the actual question? Please read [ask] and create a [mcve] of what you tried because this website is not a code writing service

Comment: thank you sir Alon Eitan to inform me how to drop a proper post/question here.

Comment: The most important thing is that you include the code that you tried because it will help us to better understand the issue you're having. We need to see the HTML structure and the relevant JAVASCRIPT code

Answer (score 0):

using jquery the code will looks likes this
let me know if you are using .net

```
<input type="text" id="text1">
<input type="text" id="text2">
<input type="text" id="text3" readonly>
<script>
$('#text1').change(function(){
   validate()
})
$('#text2').change(function(){
   validate()    
})
function validate(){
   var text1 = $('#text1').val();
   var text2 = $('#text2').val();
   if(text1 == "Pedro" && text2 == "Juan"){
      $('#text3').val("Boy");
   }
   if(text1 == "Ana" && text2 == "Marie"){
      $('#text3').val("Girl");
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: let me know if i help you, maybe i cant undestand your problem

Comment: im not using .net? i write it in notepad++ and run in a browser

Comment: This would work if this was the only names that a user could type. I am assuming the OP wants to be able to type in any combination of names and for the system to just "know" the gender types of the names.